# How should I tag on Letterboxd?

Tags: letterboxd

I wanted to rate a movie on letterboxd and I was not sure what I should be tagging the movie with. Should it be organization for me or for others to see? Should genres and actors be going in there?

[image: Tagging the Good, Bad and the Ugly]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags on Letterboxd are primarily for your own use, although they are also visible and searchable by others. Tags added to a film by you are not added to the film for other users, so they're more useful for you to categorize films for your own use, where or with whom you saw the film, etc. (Separate views of a film by you can have different tags too, for example "dvd" vs. "cinema".) Actors need not be tagged unless you want to, as they are listed and cross-referenced on the film page. We have genre information from TMDb, although we're not surfacing that on the site at present, as it can be a bit patchy, so tagging your own films with genres can be useful for the future.

Comment: Would you mind editing your profile (you may need to register) and mention that you work/worked on Letterboxd?